# Magento - Insert contact form in CMS page error

Tags: forms, magento, contacts

Hy,

Magento version 1.9.0.1

I have made a new cms page and inserted this code initially `{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' form_action='/contacts/index/post' template='contacts/mycontactform.phtml'}}` . Created another form called mycontactform.phtml in the same folder as the form.phtml. After submit i get this error: `The requested URL /contacts/index/post was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Then i have tried with the standard form `{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' form_action='/contacts/index/post' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}` . I get same error.

I have to mention that Contact us page it's working with form.phtml.

If anyone knows, please help.

Thank you,

Comment: I have mannaged to solve the `404 not found error`. I was using subdomain. Now if i am using any of them it gets me to the contact page. In my custom form mycontactform.phtml i have a custom field added. It's not taken into email.

Answer (score 0):

Try doble quotes instead, this works for me:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: i add this code in my CMS page, form appears but on submit, it gives me error 404. this is the URL its redirecting to, after submit:
https://www.peterwynnscore.com.au/contacts/index/post

Comment: can you try ```{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}``` and reindex